# Unhandled Rejection (Error): call revert exception

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ethereum, solidity, erc20

I am getting this error message when trying to interact with my smart contract on my react front end. I am running localhost3000 and which  requires metamask to sign in.

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): call revert exception (method="symbol()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.0.8)
Logger.makeError
/Users/username/Desktop/final-4/src.ts/index.ts:205
Logger.throwError
/Users/username/Desktop/final-4/src.ts/index.ts:217
Interface.decodeFunctionResult
/Users/username/Desktop/final-4/src.ts/interface.ts:326
  323 |     eventFragment = this.getEvent(eventFragment);
  324 | }
  325 | const topics = [];
> 326 | const dataTypes = [];
      | ^  327 | const dataValues = [];
  328 | if (!eventFragment.anonymous) {
  329 |     topics.push(this.getEventTopic(eventFragment));

View compiled
Contract.<anonymous>
/Users/username/Desktop/final-4/src.ts/index.ts:309
fulfilled
http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:5079:24
```

Also from the source tab in inspect:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception (method="symbol()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.0.8)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception (method="balanceOf(address)", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.0.8)

Here is my directory structure:

```
client
|--node_modules
|-—public
   |—-src
   |—-contracts
      |—-Address.json
      |—-Context.json
      |—-ERC20.json
      |—-IERC20.json
      |—-Migrations.json
      |—-PreciousChicken.json
      |——SafeMath.json
   |—-App.css
   |—-App.js
   |—-App.test.js
   |—-index.css
   |—-logo.svg
   |—-reportWebVitalls.js
   |—-setupTests.js
   |—-gitignore
   |—-package-lock.json
   |—-package.json
   |—-yarn.lock
|—-contracts
   |—-Migrations.sol
   |—-MyPreciousToken
   |—-migrations
      |—-1_initial_migations.js
      |—-2_deploy_contracts.js
|—-node-modules
|—-test
```

Comment: Can you post the code that causes the error?

Comment: Hi @FastDeveloper I don't know how to find it.

Comment: Right click on the page, click Inspect and then go to the Console tab.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post the lines that caused this error?

Comment: I don't know how to find them. It looks like its in an "index.ts" file but, not sure where that is.

Comment: How does your directory structure look like?

Comment: What files do you have in src?

Comment: @FastDeveloper I have provided the directory structure above.

Comment: Do not forget to connect your Metamask account to your DAPP, the error, then, gone away for me.

Answer (score 7):

This error (CALL_EXCEPTION) happens when your smart contract is not deployed yet.

Wait the transaction ends:

```
await contract.deployTransaction.wait()
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error because I was trying to use a contract's Ropsten address instead of it's Mainnet address. Make sure that whatever contract you're using is deployed and is on the correct network.

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason was when I redeployed the contract, the contract's json files generated in the build needed to be replaced in my react app as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Connecting a proper test network in the wallet could prevent this issue while you are building a smart contract in the test network.
E.g for me, I had to connect Rinkeby network in the wallet, but actually pointing a main network.

Answer (score 2):

Double check that your contract is deoloyed on what ever test network you are using !
I ran `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost` while my testnet was running in a seperate terminal and, it fixed the error.

hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your local blockchain network `npx hardhat node` is running in a separate terminal and access the local network console in a separate terminal `npx hardhat console --network localhost`.

If the error still pops up for the commands fired in the terminal of local network console, then
The way to resolve the issue is to check the logs presented in the terminal where your local blockchain network is running.

For my case I created the contract instance with wrong address. And every time I did  try to execute the functions of the contract instance created with wrong address, for each execution there was a log in the terminal running the local blockchain network as :

```
WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f......................266
To:                  0xf39fd6e51aad88f......................266
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try to deploy the main contract again**.

Run the below commands in separate terminals parallelly

```
npx hardhat node

npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to access an element of a public array that didn't exist. The array had only one element inside so I had to change from index `1` to `0`.

````
const elIndex = ethers.BigNumber.from(0);
await ExampleContract.nfts(elIndex);
```
````